# Machine Learning: Combining Binary Encoder and RobustScaler

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-preprocessing, feature-scaling

I have a dataset with numerical and categorical data. The data includes outliner, which are essential for interpretation later. I’ve binary encoded the categorical data and used the `RobustScaler` on the numerical data.

The categorical binary encoded data does not get scaled. Is this combination possible or is there a logical error?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here.  You are asking if it is logically coherent to use numerical and categorical data?

Comment: yes, not scaling binary encoded categorial data, while using RobustScaler on numerical data in one dataset in the preprocessing process

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to scale categorical data.  If it's binary categorical data I'm not really sure what "scaling" it would mean.  Having categorical and numerical data seems perfectly fine though.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why you couldn't do that, but there's also no point.

The reason why you scale input features to be on roughly the same scale is that lots of inference methods get tripped up by features which are on vastly different scales. See [Why does feature scaling improve the convergence speed for gradient descent?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/55656/why-does-feature-scaling-improve-the-convergence-speed-for-gradient-descent) for more.

A binary feature which ranges from 0 to 1 and a continuous feature where the 25-75% percentile range from -1 to 1 are already on approximately the same scale.

Since a binary feature is easier to interpret than a scaled binary feature, I would just leave it and not apply another scaling method.

Comment: So the overall weighting is not distorted?

Comment: What do you mean by overall? Over all features? Over all training examples?

Comment: i mean, if the values of the binary scaled have only 0 or 1, these are also the min and max values respectively. These are then compared with other possibly smaller min and larger max values resulting from the RobustScaler. Is then the comparison legitimate? Or does this subsequently distort the result in the ML procedure, since the weighting is possibly not logical?

Comment: The min and max values don't have to be the same for all features. When people talk about making sure all your features have the same variance, they are talking about features with 1000x differences in variance. A difference of 2x or 5x does not matter.